# Magento 2, Change On hover instead of 'click' for mini cart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, magento-2.1.2, store-switcher

In magento 2. 
For mini cart and store switcher, they are dropdown with click.
How to change on hover instead of 'click'.

I had tried with jquery trigger click, but It don't work.

Comment: Can take reference of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64518/on-hover-instead-of-click-for-mini-cart-and-top-account-buttons-in-magento-rwd

Comment: Thank you, But it is magento 1.9 not magento 2.0

Comment: Please check answer if works :)

Answer (score 20):

In the file 
`magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml` (or an override `magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\YourTheme\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\minicart.phtml`) in the `data-mage-init` attribute use the following:

```
"triggerEvent": "hover"
"closeOnMouseLeave": true
```

and remove `"timeout": "2000"`

Example code:

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
         data-role="dropdownDialog"
         data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
            "triggerEvent" : "hover",
            "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
            "triggerTarget":".showcart",
            "closeOnMouseLeave": true,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "triggerClass":"active",
            "parentClass":"active",
            "buttons":[]}}'>
        <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using the native `data-mage-init` attribute's magento functionality. As long as you include the event you can define a number of other attributes such as:

1. `closeOnMouseLeave`
2. `closeOnEscape`
3. `triggerClass`
4. `parentClass`
5. `timeout`
6. `triggerTarget`

There are more of these that are littered through the magento templates. So for this example, you could have the following ont he `.block-minicart` element in the  `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml` template (roughly line 40):

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "triggerEvent":"hover",
                "timeout": "1000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": true,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make **minicart.phtml** structure like this

Default structure

```
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
<!--- Content --------> 
</div>
```

Add below div just above

`<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">` to `minicart.phtml`

```
<div class="container">
    <div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
        <!--- Content --------> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Remove below code from **block block-minicart empty** div

```
data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'
```

Add below Js code to **minicart.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/mage"
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.container').hover(function () {
                $(this).children('.minicart-wrapper,.action showcart').addClass("active");
                $(this).children('.ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front mage-dropdown-dialog').show();

            }, function () {
                $(this).children('.minicart-wrapper,.action showcart').removeClass("active");
                $(this).children('.ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front mage-dropdown-dialog').hide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now minicart content display on hover insted of on click.

Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 2):

**magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml**

Override By

**magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\YourTheme\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\minicart.phtml**

```
<div class="container">
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/mage"
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.container').hover(function () {
                $(this).children('.minicart-wrapper,.action showcart').addClass("active");
                $(this).children('.ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front mage-dropdown-dialog').show();

            }, function () {
                $(this).children('.minicart-wrapper,.action showcart').removeClass("active");
                $(this).children('.ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front mage-dropdown-dialog').hide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It working for me.
`<script type="text/javascript"> require([ "jquery", "mage/mage" ], function ($) { $(document).ready(function () { $('.container').hover(function () { $(this).find('.minicart-wrapper,.action.showcart').addClass(‌​"active"); $(this).find('.ui-widget-content').show(); }, function () { $(this).find('.minicart-wrapper,.action.showcart').removeCla‌​ss("active"); $(this).find('.ui-widget-content').hide(); }); }); }); </script>`

Comment: I added above code but its not working.

Comment: @Jal you can check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="container">
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/mage"
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.container').hover(function () {
                $(this).children('.minicart-wrapper,.action showcart').addClass("active");
                $(this).children('.ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front mage-dropdown-dialog').show();

            }, function () {
                $(this).children('.minicart-wrapper,.action showcart').removeClass("active");
                $(this).children('.ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front mage-dropdown-dialog').hide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**This code also working too fine . You  need to add a css like** , **.minicart-wrapper.active .ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-front.mage-dropdown-dialog {
    display: block !important;
}**
**You will get an good result.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
     data-role="dropdownDialog"
     data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
        "triggerEvent" : "hover",
        "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
        "triggerTarget":".showcart",
        "timeout": "200",
        "closeOnMouseLeave": true,
        "closeOnEscape": true,
        "triggerClass":"active",
        "parentClass":"active",
        "buttons":[]}}'>
    <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer #5 is the correct answer however, the Timeout can be used to set how long the mini cart stays visible after mouse leave. The default is 500, but I've seen quirks in leaving it out. Setting it to "timeout": "200" seems to work fine for me.
Adding inline JS as in Answers #1 & #3 should be avoided.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Its better to add code in your answer rather then giving reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

The Above code works fine in 2.2.4

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
     data-role="dropdownDialog"
     data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
        "triggerEvent" : "hover",
        "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
        "triggerTarget":".showcart",
        "timeout": "200",
        "closeOnMouseLeave": true,
        "closeOnEscape": true,
        "triggerClass":"active",
        "parentClass":"active",
        "buttons":[]}}'>
    <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who have upgraded to 2.4.5, `"triggerEvent" : "hover",` may not work in this instance.

In my case, changing it to `"triggerEvent" : "mouseenter",` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys but most of you missed something important. Instead of using 'hover' we should use 'mouseenter'

```
<div class="block block-minicart"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerEvent":"mouseenter",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
```