# Change timeout for dropdown in magento 2

Tags: magento2, drop-downs, timeout

I need to change the `timeout` for the dropdowns of `megamenu`, 
`cart icon` and `my account`.
I found the `dropdown.js` file in the `Mage` folder but I am not able to understand from where do I change the timeout. 
But I don't think `dropdown.js` is the right file

I referred this *link* for mini cart

> [Magento 2, Change On hover instead of 'click' for mini cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150159/magento-2-change-on-hover-instead-of-click-for-mini-cart/160082/)

Not able to find the same for `Magamenu` and 'My account' dropdown at the top header